# Overriding nsIWindowWatcher Component

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm writing Firefox Addon that instead of opening content in new windows could open a content in new tab or sidebar.

There are [several ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Opening_windows) to open windows:

- `window.open()`
- `window.openDialog()` or...
- using `openWindow()` function form the component `@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1` by [nsIWindowWatcher](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowWatcher) interface

I override window.open and window.openDialog and it seems to work but I have problem with overriding `openWindow()` function in window-watcher component.

I override whole component because I don't know how to override only specify functions. For now I implement all functions of the component and redirect them to internal original component `this._WindowWatcher=Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowWatcher)` in a way like this function:

```
getWindowByName : function(/* in wstring */ aTargetName, /* in nsIDOMWindow */ aCurrentWindow)  // --> nsIDOMWindow;
{
    var all_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // convert to Array
    return this._WindowWatcher.getWindowByName.apply(this._WindowWatcher, all_args);    
},
```

Then I register the component using XPCOMUtils.jsm and nsIComponentRegistrar :

```
var NSGetFactory = XPCOMUtils.generateNSGetFactory([WindowWatcher]);
var WindowWatcherFactory = NSGetFactory(WindowWatcher.prototype.classID);
var nsIComponentRegistrar = Components.manager
                            .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIComponentRegistrar);
var oldCID = nsIComponentRegistrar
             .contractIDToCID("@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1");
nsIComponentRegistrar.registerFactory(
       WindowWatcher.prototype.classID, 
       null, 
       "@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1", 
       WindowWatcherFactory
);
```

Then this seems work when I use directly Window Watcher in JavaScript:

```
 ww = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
      .getService(Ci.nsIWindowWatcher)
 var win = ww.openWindow(null, "about:home",
                     "_blank", "chrome,centerscreen", null);
```

But when Firefox would like internally use the overriden component (e.g. clicking link on error item in Console; probably Firefox is using [nsGlobalWindow::OpenDialog](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/nsGlobalWindow.cpp#6473)), it causes error :

```
  NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff 
  (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMJSWindow.openDialog]
```

---

My extension is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhazuxurt40716m/moreICUIPlus.xpi) (overriding component module in `modules\window-watcher.jsm`)

For tests I use Firebug Console on chrome context or JavaScript Shell in [Developer Assistant](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extension-developer) addon and import my component module `Components.utils.import("resource://moreICUIPlus/window-watcher.jsm");`

Thanks for every possible hints.

Comment: I didn't really dig too deep into your code, but here are some issues I saw: 1) Do not implement nsISupports yourself. AddRef/Release will be auto-implemented. 2) Your component does not implement nsPIWindowWatcher, which the original one does. 3) using `debugger;` is probably not a very good idea. 4) the `.slice.call(arguments)/.apply`scheme won't really always work when overriding XPCOM components IIRC.

Comment: @nmaier 
Thanks for sharing your thoughts. About (2) I implemented interfaces that are accessible from javascript ([enumerateInterfaces](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=WZ3f--WHk72__G9EP4qjU5gq5NM&cid=wZKBjpj2Txs&s=&browser=Default&fp=400454&mpundefined&projSelected=true#L84) in Log4moz). (Maybe from native code there are more interfaces that should be implemented also... Probably I need to see original code)

Comment: I didn't even notice: nsPIWindowWatcher is not scriptable, hence you cannot implement in in JS. Hence you cannot fully override nsIWindowWatcher in a compatible way without resorting to C++. And C++ in add-ons is really a PITA. BTW: I usually use mxr for fast code lookups: http://mxr.mozilla.org/ . There is also http://dxr.mozilla.org/, but is is somewhat buggy and mozilla-central only AFAIK. The definition of what the platform window-watcher implements is here e.g.: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/embedding/components/windowwatcher/src/nsWindowWatcher.cpp#242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so that one does not need to skim the comments:

Re-implementing (wrapping) the `@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1` component in a javascript component is not possible, because one would need to implement the non-scriptable `nsPIWindowWatcher` interface.

Re-implementing (wrapping) it in a C++ component would be possible, but in context of add-ons isn't very feasible, because one would need to compile for all supported OS/platforms, and one would need to recompile for each version of Gecko, as binary-components are version-tagged and won't load if the Gecko versions don't match.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. [XULPlanet](https://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=site%3Axulplanet.mozdev.org%20%22%40mozilla.org%2Fembedcomp%2Fwindow-watcher%3B1%22) also mentions about nsPIWinowWatcher non-scriptable interface in this component.

I think maybe I turn away of overriding openWindow function in the Window-watcher component. (unless there is other way to do this ) Most of opening window operations use `window.open()`/`window.openDialog()`.

Comment: XULPlanet is outdated/not updated onymore IIRC. Better use [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/embedding/components/windowwatcher/public/nsPIWindowWatcher.idl#19), which has the actual definition, and shows the interface lacks `scriptable`. In general, if you want to wrap a component in JS, all implemented interfaces must be wrapped, therefore all intefaces must be `scriptable` with no member being marked `noscript`.